# How many degrees of freedom does a $3×3$ non-singular system of linear equation have?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the system of linear equations:$$\begin{bmatrix}-3&2&-6\\5&7&-5\\1&4&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}.$$
If we set $a = 6$, $b = 6$, $c = 8$, we can solve for $x$, $y$, $z$, so when we replace all of the values of the right-most column vector, we can solve for $x$, $y$, $z$. This seems to suggest that this system of linear equations has three degrees of freedom. But I still don't know the following two questions.

1. If we plug in **any** three of $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$, $y$, $z$, can we derive the other three?
2. What theorem relates the type of $n \times m$ system with the number of degrees of freedom it has? Keep in mind that an $n \times m$ has $n + m$ unplugged variables (yes, we are considering the "constant terms", that is, the RHS, as unknown variables).

Comment: NB if we denote the $3 \times 3$ matrix by $A$, and denote ${\bf x} = \pmatrix{x&y&z}^\top$ and ${\bf a} = \pmatrix{a&b&c}^\top$ then we can rewrite the system $S{\bf x} = {\bf a}$ as
$$\pmatrix{S & \vert & -I} \pmatrix{{\bf x} \\ {\bf a}} = 0 .$$ Since the $3 \times 6$ matrix has full rank, the solution space has dimension $3$. On the other hand, fixing three of the variables corresponds to fixing a $3$-dimensional affine plane parallel to three of the coordinate hyperplanes, and whether this determines the three remaining variables is just asking whether these two $3$-planes are transverse.

Comment: @Travis make this into an answer so I can upvote you and grant you the green checkmark.

Comment: I deliberately wrote a comment, since I didn't think the remark answered your question. But if it satisfies you, I'm happy to oblige---please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB if we denote the $3 \times 3$ matrix by $A$, and denote ${\bf x} = \pmatrix{x&y&z}^\top$ and ${\bf a} = \pmatrix{a&b&c}^\top$, then we can rewrite the given system $S {\bf x} = {\bf a}$ as the linear system
$$\pmatrix{S&-I}\pmatrix{{\bf x}\\{\bf a}} = {\bf 0}$$
Since $\pmatrix{S&-I}$ has rank $3$, the solution space has dimension $3$. On the other hand, fixing three of the variables corresponds to fixing a $3$-dimensional affine plane parallel to three of the coordinate hyperplanes, and whether this determines the three remaining variables is just asking whether these two $3$-planes are transverse. This depends on the particular entries of $S$ and the choices of which variables are fixed.